# Using mouse actions with Packery library after expanding an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, packery

I've made a fork ([click](http://codepen.io/Colorblind-Seb/pen/ByYWVQ)) on Codepen form David DeSandro's "Packery - animate item width and height, with responsive sizing". As you can see when you click on the button inside an item it expands and a black tint covers the whole canvas. Click on it again, contracts and the black tint is gone. What I can't wrap my head around is when someone clicks outside the item when expanded, like on the `<body>`, item contracts and the black tint's gone. If anyone can help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked your CodePen - [take a look here](http://codepen.io/ramsaylanier/pen/KwQJvx).

Basically, in your click eventListener on the body element, you have to do the following:

```
$("body").click(function(event){
  //check if body has overlay-layer, meaning an item is expanded
  if ($(event.target).hasClass('overlay-layer')){
    $(this).removeClass('overlay-layer');
    $('.item').removeClass('is-expanded');
    $container.packery();
  }
});
```